# Boost C++ normalize string accent

Tags: c++, boost, normalize

I would like to replace all accents from a string. So I use boost::local::normalize. But not all the accent are correctly replaced.

For exemple I have this french word : "Côté", the function normalize only remove "é" and replace it by "e" but for "ô" it replace it by "^"

```cpp
static boost::locale::generator gen;
static auto loc = gen("");
std::string str = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(boost::locale::normalize("Côté",boost::locale::norm_nfd, loc), "ISO8859-1");
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

str = c^te

If someone know what is wrong.